# Scrolling gnome-terminal output programmatically?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, sh

Is there some way to automatically scroll to the beginning of the terminal output from sh script?

I have custom build routine in my development process:
sh script is using inotifywait to detect source files changes and runs various stuff like rendering templates, checking syntax, compiling sources etc.
I clear terminal on each change first and then do the rest, so all the terminal output is always relevant only to most recent changes in the sources.

But if there are errors, usually there are plenty of them cascaded by each other,
I want to see very first error first, but it always requires manual scrolling terminal output to the top.

Most of the time terminal is not focused so emulating keystrokes will not work (unless it's possible to send keystrokes to current terminal window only.)

UPD:
I tried to use xdotool - for terminal it works only when sending keys to current active window. I tried to use --window option of key command and also chaining key command after search - nothing happens.

Comment: If all you want to see are messages printed on standard error, why not just redirect the standard output stream of the running shell with e.g. `exec > /dev/null` so you will only see error messages (given they are printed to file descriptor 2) ... However, some terminal related commands like `clear` will need to be redirected like `clear >&2` to work in that case.

Comment: In my script I first evaluate templates to generate Rust sources, then I check syntax by running rust compiler (cargo check), which gives nice colored output both with warnings and errors. I guess separating error stream will ruin all this beauty? And still it usually have quite a lot errors if there are any, because they kinda trigger each other and compiler tries to check full sources even if first error encountered (no option to limit this). So even with error out only - it's still quite a long text usually not fitting into full-screen terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible (at least not without modifying its source).

I recommend to redirect the build script's output to a pager, such as `less`.

`xdotool` is indeed limited due to security concerns, and GNOME is transitioning from X11 towards Wayland where I think it's not possible to do anything like this.

The terminal has a "Scroll on output" preference, but first you'd have to produce a bit more than a screenful of data and then scroll it back a little bit, so that the bottom of the output is not visible, and once you manually do this then new output no longer snaps back the viewport to the bottom. This is not quite what you're looking for.

The scrollbar is designed to be in the user's control, not adjusted programatically.

---

Update: You should apply this patch to [VTE](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/), the engine behind GNOME Terminal, for your desired behavior:

```
--- a/src/vte.cc
+++ b/src/vte.cc
@@ -3931,7 +3931,7 @@ Terminal::process_incoming()
                 /* Keep the cursor on-screen if we scroll on output, or if
                  * we're currently at the bottom of the buffer. */
                 update_insert_delta();
-                if (m_scroll_on_output || context.m_bottom) {
+                if (m_scroll_on_output) {
                         maybe_scroll_to_bottom();
                 }
                 /* Deselect the current selection if its contents are changed
```

Compile with `meson` and `ninja`, then run the test app as `./src/app/vte-2.91`.

I recommend you to run your build script inside this VTE test app.

Of course you can install this modified libvte system-wide, but then all your terminals will behave this way, which is probably not what you want. Or, to have the real GNOME Terminal experience, install the library elsewhere, and fiddle with manually starting up `gnome-terminal-server` with a non-default `--app-id a.b` or so, along with a custom `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find the modified VTE, and then connect to it via a corresponding `gnome-terminal --app-id a.b` to open a window... Or add a new API for this behavior. Or add a custom escape sequence that enables this behavior for the given terminal... it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Yes I already tried using less, but my script is running continuously and react on source files changes and on each iteration it clears everything and generate new output version, less seems overwhelmed by such a use case, renders first part but then goes crazy when you try to scroll the rest..
Maybe I just need to resize my terminal and make it excessively high so bottom part will be even below the screen edge, then scrollbar will never appear and I will always see first lines of output :)

Comment: I'm wondering if you could programatically kill `less` and start a new one.

Comment: Please see the update to the answer (I don't know if you get notified about that :))

Comment: OMG looks seductively but I am not familiar with c++ so afraid to spend more time setting up all the tools, compiling and making this running than for the rest of my current project where I have such a non-conventional build process... Ok challenge accepted, in case of success I will have such an achievement to count myself as part of c++ elite legion, even if on rookie level :)
Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: Report from battlefield: 
I started fine by trying build it with meson, installed few missing deps but then GTK4.12.+ appeared and started laughing on my Ubuntu 22.04 where maximum is GTK4.6.3
Now I guess I have two options - compile fresh GTK4 myself which is scary.
Or try find older branch of VTE where GTK4.6.3 is still fine.
I see there was recent commit: Oct 14, 2023 bump GTK requirement to 4.12 
Before it it was gtk4.0 so will try to get previous version

Comment: Made your suggested changes and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Just saw your previous post, I was just about to suggest to go with a slightly older VTE version, probably the one matching your distro. Anyway, I'm glad you managed to make it work :)